# Fetching unix users from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security, unix

We have some tables where we store some sensitive information. These tables have one extra column "ModifiedBy". Currently we insert the value for this column programmatically.

Is there a way to get the current unix user into SQL Server. The idea is to auto-populate the user name/id into that column with the use of triggers.

Comment: You have SQL Server running on a Unix machine? Wow.

Comment: @Frank - I didn't know SQL Server == Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the language or situation, so an answer is hard ...

presuming users are logged in and running a program, and that this program is a scripting language then you can execute `whoami` from the shell and use that value.

If you are using C, then see geteuid() and friends.

Comment: My apologies for being not-so-clear. I am using java. In java I can surely fetch the current user and put that value in the column.
Actually my intention is not to do this explicitly.
I want SQL Server to identify the current user. I could use that value in a trigger that updates the “ModifiedBy” for the updated/inserted rows.

But as the things stand, a web application can run on any platform/operating-system and it is that applications duty to provide the current user information to the database.

Thanks
Nayn